# update a column from one table with multiplied value from column from another table

Tags: opencart

I have 2 tables, first `product` with a column `price` and second `product_reward` with a column `points`.
I'd like to update the column `points` with the value from column `price`*0.1.
So points=price*01.

Thanks!

Comment: this has not to do much with opencart, you will have to perform a sql query for this, and to get answers here, you have to show what have tried for that sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following sql query to update current reward points of products.

```
UPDATE `oc_product_reward` rp SET rp.`points`=(SELECT p.price FROM `oc_product` p WHERE rp.`product_id` = p.`product_id`)*0.1
```

After that, you have to update your product model of admin part. insert and update part of `upload/admin/model/catalog/product.php`

```
    if (isset($data['product_reward'])) {
        foreach ($data['product_reward'] as $customer_group_id => $product_reward) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', customer_group_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "', points = '" . (int)((float)$data['price'] * 0.1) . "'");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi and thank you very much, is working :D And now it's auto updating :d Can it be done the same for the total amount, just the admin part, so the total points for which a product can be bought to be price x 2? The sql part for the existing product I figure it out..

Comment: sorry, i dont understand what you want exactly. do you want update for older order?

Comment: No, I'd like if possible to update the total amount of reward points needed to buy a product so it would equal price x 2. But just only the admin part.

Comment: and if you know well opencart I need also a module for a custom option for products and i'm willing to pay for that, please let me know. thanks.

Comment: if this answer is correct for your first question, can you accept it? On the otherhand, I can help you for your module. you can mail me from haydarkulekci(a)hotmail.com .